# Incremental backup with 7zip

Tags: backup, 7-zip, incremental-backup

I have googled and searched, but can't find the command that 7zip command line utility uses for making incremental backups. So can someone please share the command ?

Thanks

btw I found this link: http://wmug.co.uk/wmug/b/sean/archive/2009/03/20/powershell-amp-7zip-incremental-backup-solution.aspx . But it seems to be for differential backups, even though it says incremental.

Answer (score 17):

Should be simple, use this to create and incrementally update the archive:

```
7zr u -up0q3r2x2y2z1w2 {archive}.7z {path}
```

[This page](http://sevenzip.sourceforge.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/update.htm) offers a reference for the update options.

They are translated as follows:

- `p0` - If "File exists in archive, but is not matched with wildcard" then remove the file from the archive.
- `q3` - If "File exists in archive, but doesn't exist on disk" then remove the file from the archive *and remove it from the filesystem upon extraction*.
- `r2` - If "File doesn't exist in archive, but exists on disk" then pack the file into the archive.
- `x2` - If "File in archive is newer than the file on disk" then "compress file from disk to new archive".
- `y2` - If "File in archive is older than the file on disk" then pack the newer file into the archive.
- `z1` - If "File in archive is same as the file on disk" then reuse the packed version of the file.
- `w2` - If file size is different then pack the modified file into the archive.

Note that only the **compression is incremental**: that is, 7-Zip will only compress the updates, reusing compressed files that were not updated. The file with the archive will still be **re-created** by 7-Zip.

Comment: Hello, what do those many options mean?

Comment: It's a map from a file state to an action. There are seven possible states.

Comment: It's not an incremental backup. This command makes a differential backup and creates new archive with changes since last full backup. Incremental backup tracks changes since previous incremental backup (diff of diff).

Comment: I think this is plain wrong, in that it just updates archive.7z to be almost the same as just creating a new archive, but a bit quicker as it will reuse.  Javier's answer below seems to be a differential.

Comment: When the archive is large and the increments are small the "*bit quicker*" is quite substantial. Not repacking the entire archive is one of the points of the incremental backups. Also, this is not a differential backup: we're updating the main archive and not storing the difference in a separate archive. If you like the other solutions more, feel free to upvote them, there's more than one way to skin a cat.

Comment: Great solution @ArtemGr! Side remark: if we add password encryption, it does not seem to work anymore: if only 1 MB is changed in a 10GB archive, the full 10GB will sadly be rewritten during the update: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/624419/59989. Do you have an idea for this?

Comment: Note @ArtemGr: even without *password encryption*, doing `7z u ...` rewrites the full archive! Example here with a 1GB archive, I modified only 1 file in the source dir, I did the command you suggested, result: in the meantime a `.tmp` file is created and the full content of the archive is entirely rewritten: see https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAjns.png. Is it the same for you?

Comment: @Basj, Sure, and that's to be expected, you'd need a special writeable-database-like file format in order for the archiver to optimize the I/O, 7-Zip never specialized in that. I've added a note in the answer.
The problem with database-like formats is that they typically have a space overhead, so efficient updates and archivers very seldom do mix. I've seen some attempts to implement them, but never a finished one.  D

Answer (score 12):

If you were to do an [incremental backup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_backup), you would need to provide 7-zip with the list of the files modified (with `-i@fileList`), and you would need to elaborate such list somehow. At the archive.org mirror of removed question [Offline incremantal backup via thumbdrive](https://web.archive.org/web/20151228095434/http://superuser.com/questions/862323/offline-incremental-backup-via-thumbdrive) you can find a Unix command line using md5 signatures to create the fileList.

The 7-zip update operation allows to create a secondary archive with the differences (including deleted files) occurring since the base/primary archive. That is properly named a differential backup (as stated in the question itself).

I've found an excellent article on this topic at [WPCTips "Differential Backups with 7-zip"(archived)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160822111118/http://www.wpctips.com:80/7zipdiff.html). They recommend either using a GUI program (Toucan), or use this recipe for the command line:

```
7z u {base archive.7z} -u- -"up0q3r2x2y2z0w2!{differential.7z}" {folder to archive}
```

This is a bit different from the `7zr u -up0q3r2x2y2z1w2 {archive}.7z {path}` proposed by ArtemGr:

- `-u-` tells the main archive should not be modified
- `"-up0q3r2x2y2z0w2!{differential.7z}"` specifies the target differential archive, and what action to do for each file for each condition/state: add files which are new or modified in the filesystem, remove files which are only in the 7zip archive, ignore the rest.
  Notice that the "!" character will be intercepted by `bash` unless it is quoted.

Just in case you are curious about the specifics of that cryptic `p0q3r2x2y2z0w2`

```
<state> | State condition
p | File exists in archive, but is not matched with wildcard.   Exists, but is   not matched 
q | File exists in archive, but doesn't exist on disk.
r | File doesn't exist in archive, but exists on disk.
x | File in archive is newer than the file on disk.
y | File in archive is older than the file on disk.
z | File in archive is same as the file on disk
w | Can not be detected what file is newer (times are the same, sizes are different)

<action> | Description 
0 | Ignore file (don't create item in new archive for this file) 
1 | Copy file (copy from old archive to new) 
2 | Compress (compress file from disk to new archive) 
3 | Create Anti-item (item that will delete file or directory during extracting). This feature is supported only in 7z format.
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Javier, and welcome to Super User. There is a policy here of summarising links in case they disappear- could you explain how the command achieves the incremental backup? (particularly the `up0q3r2x2y2z0w2` part!) Thanks :-)

Comment: @bertieb thank you for advice. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Could you clarify if I need to extract each intermediate differential backups in order to get to the desired state? - is 7zip smart enough to do this for me?

Comment: @DanielSokolowski Not sure if this answers your question. If you did an incremental backup (A+b+c+d), you will have to extract from each archive in the order you made them. If you did a differential backup (A+(b+c+d)). It is 2 archives you have to extract. It would be nice that the last archive contained information about previous archives and order of extraction, so extraction could be made with a single command. But I am not aware  of such feature.

Comment: article you share does not open @Javier

Comment: Thanks @alper . Archive.org has some snapshot of the extint WPC Tips article at https://web.archive.org/web/20160822111118/http://www.wpctips.com:80/7zipdiff.html . I guess I will have to amend the response.

Comment: From https://web.archive.org/web/20170121203434/https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/update.htm, best to put folder/pattern to archive at end.

Answer (score 6):

You can easily do an incremental backup via changing the direction in time. i.e. you always keep the latest backup as a full copy and keep differential files into the past.

```
# create the difference step into the past
7z u {base archive.7z} {folder to archive} -mx=9 -u- -up1q1r3x1y1z0w1!{decrement.7z}

# update the Archive to the latest files
7z u {base archive.7z} {folder to archive} -mx=9 -up0q0x2
```

The base Archive always contains the latest version and via applying the "decrements" step by step you can recreate older Versions. With a little bit scripting you can apply the right numbering to the decremental files.

Comment: Can you kindly elaborate on this? I'd love to see an example of creating say a current backup, backup 1 day ago, backup 2 days ago. And then an example of restoring the '2 days ago' backup.

Answer (score 0):

In a batch file, with enabledelayedexpansion, you need to quote the "!" with two ^^ like this

```
7z u {existing archive.7z} -u- -up0q3r2x2y2z0w2^^!{new differential.7z} {folder or files to archive}
```

Took me a while to see that one.